# page numbering appearing only for pages containing chapter title

Tags: page-numbering

I have a problem with page numbering. I was given a template for styling chapter titles but apparently this removes the page numbering for all pages except the pages which have chapter title on it.

here is the template:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside, table]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot]{geometry}

%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{utf8}

    % Nicer default font than Computer Modern for most use cases
 %   \usepackage{palatino}

 \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}%

\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
%\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{color}%
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{tabu}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%

\usepackage{subcaption}

\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} % à inclure si on utilise \usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

%\include{boilerpalte}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\def\myformat#1{\centering#1}

%
\definecolor{C3D69B}{HTML}{C3D69B}%
\definecolor{000000}{HTML}{000000}%
%

%%
% chapter style
%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule\Huge}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\Huge}
[\titlerule]

%%
% part style
%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{emptyx}%   % Original »plain« replaced by »emptyx
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{PRÉSENTATION DU
CADRE DU PROJET}
\section{Introduction}\label{introChap1}

xxxxxxxxThis page don't have a number

\section{Cadre du Projet}\label{L1Chap1}

yyyy



\end{document}
```

my questions are :

- what's provoking this behavior?
- and what can I do do fix this?

EDIT:
what I want is to enable numbers on all pages.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  unfortunately, there's one very important piece of information missing -- the `\documentclass`.  that is where the basic style of running heads is usually defined.  please extend your example to be compilable -- starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  you can use dummy text (packages like `lipsum` and `blindtext` can help with that) to avoid including private information.  then we can answer without having to consult our crustal balls.  (mine is usually out of commission.)

Comment: thx for your welcoming message, you are not like SO you don't crush beginners, appreciate, Edit the code

Comment: This issue has come up in several previous queries. Basically, with the `book` document class, LaTeX issues the directive `\thispagesstyle{plain}` every time a `\part` or `\chapter` directive is encountered. The `plain` page style is programmed to place a page number at the center of the footer line. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve: (a) suppressing page numbers on pages with chapter headers or (b) re-enabling page numbers on all other pages?

Comment: thx for the explanation, HOw can I show the numbering for all pages?

Comment: Since we don't have the files `first.tex`, `dedi.tex`, `remerciment.tex`, etc., it's not possible to compile your code. Please consider editing your code so that it becomes compilable while still generating the issues you're looking to fix.

Comment: I deleted all included files

Comment: The page number is in the middle of the footer on chapter pages. On the other pages it is in the header. This is the default behaviour of the twosided class `book`.

Answer (score 1):

The page numbers on the pages without a chapter heading are in the header.

You can use a package like `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage` to define the contents of header and footer. Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage` that puts the page number in footer for "normal" pages, too:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside, table]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in,includefoot,
  headheight=21.8pt% as suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyleset=standard,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings
\ohead{}% remove the page number from header on pages
\cfoot{\pagemark}% add the page number to footer

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}% loads also graphicx

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[french]{babel}%<- changed in french
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{longtable}%
\usepackage{tabu}%

\usepackage{subcaption}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true} % à inclure si on utilise \usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\def\myformat#1{\centering#1}

\definecolor{C3D69B}{HTML}{C3D69B}%
\definecolor{000000}{HTML}{000000}%

%%
% chapter style
%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule\Huge}
[\vspace*{\fill}\newpage]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]\Huge}
[\titlerule]

%%
% part style
%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%   % Original »plain« replaced by »empty«
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]